# When does a partially defined map from a singular curve to projective space extend?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is just something train of thought I became curious about after reading a cryptic suggestion that resolution of singularities lets us transfer our "understanding" of smooth curves to singular curves.

(Do we understand smooth curves? What is does the author - Ravi Vakil - mean? Anyway, onto the precise math question ...)

Suppose that $C$ is a singular, integral affine curve, over some algebraically closed field $k$. Let $f : C \to X$ be some rational map to a projective $k$-scheme (or just $\mathbb{P}^n_k$).

Let $C'$ be the normalization of $C$, and $\pi: C' \to C$ the normalizing map. Then the map $f \circ \pi$ extends to a regular map $j: C' \to X$, since $C'$ is regular.

I want to know when the map $f : C \to X$ will extend. There are two natural obstructions to the map $f$ extending to a map defined on all of $C'$, which come from the necessity that $j = f \circ \pi$ if $f$ extended.

Namely, for points $p,q \in C'$ which have $\pi(p) = \pi(q)$, $j(p) = j(q)$ is necessary. Also, for a point $p \in C'$, and a tangent vector $v \in T_p C'$, if $d\pi(v) = 0$, then necessarily $dj(v) = 0$.

I want to know - are these the only conditions? (They come from looking at the normalization of the nodal cubic and the cuspidal cubic respectively. So maybe my intuition about normalizations is missing some crucial example?) If $j$ satisfies the above conditions, then was it a lift of some extension of $f$ from $C$ to $X$? If not, what are the correct conditions?

I expect that some result along these lines is well known - I would appreciate very much a reference, or at least a hint of what to try.

Comment: Ok, I just didn't understand what the question was at all. I see the point, now.

Comment: @CaptainLama No, problem. Thanks for reading. :)

Comment: No, these are not the only conditions.  In particular, dj(v) has to be a nice function of the d$\pi$(v).  I don't have the time to figure out what "nice" here means; however, read Serre's Algebraic Groups and Class Fields, chapter IV.3.  A map is an extension of $f$ from $C$ to $X$ if and only if we can form a map $C'\rightarrow X$, through which $f$ would factor.  The construction of a map $C'\rightarrow C$ are described there.